# How do i properly implement axios interceptor in Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to make axios working with a request interceptor. However before a request is made the interceptor is not triggered. What could be going wrong here? I've red already a lot about this problem but not found a solution so far.In my main.js file i am using something like this.

```
import App from './App'
import router from './router'



const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
  params: {} // do not remove this, its added to add params later in the config
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  return config;
},
function (error) {
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error)
})

// Add a response interceptor
instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  // Do something with response data
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with response error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: You are using a response interceptor not a request one. Not clear what you are asking or what the specific problem is

Comment: @charlietfl i just edited and checked the same ... but still doesnt work. interceptor is not triggered yet.

Comment: In order to write self-contained single-responsibility interceptors within my apps that uses Axios, I created the [_axios-middleware_ lib](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/). It's easier to use and extend than the Axios' default interceptor API.

Comment: @EmileBergeron That's pretty slick, thanks for sharing!